# Bootstrap 4 change columns places on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On mobile I need show form search on first position (after: navbar-brand). How I can do it? I need use grid?

Comment: In bootstrap 3 you can use push and pull , But in bootstrap 4 that is not available so you'll have to use order property of flex.

Comment: Because bootstrap 4 is a flex system

Comment: What version of 4 are you using? ... `navbar-toggleable-` no longer exists

Comment: @Dumitru are you going to answer the question about version? This code is out of date. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it would work for the latest Bootstrap 4.2. You can use the `order-` classes to reorder flexbox children. Wrap the `navbar-nav` and `form` in a flexbox container (`d-flex`). This will allow you to responsively change the position. For example `order-first order-md-last` means **order last on md and up**, and **order first on less than md**...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row w-100 align-items-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline flex-nowrap my-2 my-lg-0 order-first order-md-last">
                <input class="form-control mr-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/BM9LUiAJ2E)

Comment: This is not working on tablets :(( When screen is resize, nav and search show on 2 columns

Comment: Did you see the demo? They don't show in 2 columns.